# How to choose/load between different/multiple PDF files i pdf.js

Tags: jquery, pdf.js

I'm a simple building a web application where I need to be able to read pdf files. I have found that pdf.js is a good solution.

However, I cannot seem to find a way how to switch/load between different files.

Ideally, I'd like to have a menu, such as:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" id="document1">Document 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="document2">Document 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="document3">Document 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

So when I click on any of the link above, the pdf gets loaded.

Apparently, this javascript below should be implemented, but I'm not sure how:

```
PDFJS.getDocument('helloworld.pdf')//in here I need to pass the parameter for the document
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your `a` links like `pdfopener` and then try:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li><a class="pdfopener" href="#" id="document1">Document 1</a></li>
  <li><a class="pdfopener" href="#" id="document2">Document 2</a></li>
  <li><a class="pdfopener" href="#" id="document3">Document 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.pdfopener').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        PDFJS.getDocument(id + '.pdf');
    });
});
</script>
```

Of course, you need jQuery if you want to use this code.

Comment: Your solution is not working :( What I have done was that I created a simple menu on top of the viewer.html, included jquery links and put your code on the bottom of the page. When I click any of the link, the documents are not loading and nothing is actually happening to the page/viewer :(

Comment: did you loaded the jQuery library. Does console tells you any error? Can you show me a live demo?

Comment: yes, jquery works fine, no errors in the console. Not sure I can make it work via Plunker or fiddle :(

Comment: and does document1.pdf, document2.pdf and document3.pdf is the same directory as helloworld.pdf? if you can not fiddle, do you have any live server or are you try to do it on localhost?

Comment: as i see, of course it won't work. I do not now that PDFJS, but related to this: http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/ it's not enough just get it, you need to render it.